# Set a constant value from a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some domain data in my rails application that I'm trying to create some constants for.  This is something I came across in Dan Chak's Enterprise Rails Chapter 7.  I have done the following:

```
G = Rating.find_by_rating_code('G')
```

then when I use Rating::G the appropriate Rating Record is returned.  This works great.  My problem arises due to the fact that I have 150 ratings codes.  So instead of typing the above line of code for each of my ratings codes, I was hoping to use a little meta programing to avoid cluttering up my model with a lot of redundant code.   Therefore I tried the following.

```
RATINGSCODES = %w(G A AB TR P ...)

class << self
RATINGSCODES.each do |code|
code.constantize = Rating.find_by_rating_code(code)
end
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an uninitialized constant error and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  Am I approaching this the right way.  I also tried using const_get but that didn't seem to work either.

At the suggestion below, I have also tried using

```
code.const_set = Rating.find_by_rating_code(code)
```

This yielded the following error:

```
undefined method `const_set=' for "G":String
```

Comment: Well, does the constant by the name contained in `code` actually exist already?

Comment: So you mean code.const_set = Rating.find_by_rating_code(code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_set):

```
class Rating
   RATINGSCODES = %w{ G A AB TR P }

   RATINGSCODES.each do |code|
     const_set code, code
   end
end
#=> ["G", "A", "AB", "TR", "P"] 

p Rating::G
#=> "G"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `const_set=' for "G":String.  Is const_set looking for a constant as an input?

Comment: Look at my answer again, you don't call `const_set=` on the string.  It's a class level method.  You call it, and pass the string and the value.

Comment: Ok I tried this from the irb and it didn't work. Let me throw it into the class.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. You don't need the `class << self` block.

Comment: Ok, this is interesting.  It seems this partially worked (with the class << self block. So after using your approach and then going to the IRB and typing in Rating::G.  The irb returned (loaded into memory) all the finds for the ratings codes (a good sign) but then returned the following error: NameError: uninitialized constant Rating::G

Comment: I've updated my answer witha complete example of IRB output that worked on my machine with Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Thanks so much. You were right on, it looks like the problem was having inside the class block. Once I removed the class << self block it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for you time and effort.  Hope I can return the favor sometime.

Answer (score 1):

If `Rating::G` works for you, `Raiting.const_get('G')` also will.

Comment: I believe Rating.const_get('G') retrieves the value for a constant that has already been initialized.  I'm trying to initialize the constants.

Comment: Correct, `get` retrieves an already initialized constant, while `set` creates one. I do not want to edit, as I do not want to affect OP's intention, but I am sure it was just a typo...